Error While Adding Source to Sitecore Search
I am trying to add source to sitecore search using Request Trigger , but I am getting error
Validation Error: the number of dropped documents is over the 25% of crawled documents
Error crawling request
Cause: Message:'Something went wrong for url: https://security.intuit.com/intuit-cookie-policy/', Type:, Code:0, Data:map[cause:Get "https://security.intuit.com/intuit-cookie-policy/": tls: failed to verify certificate: x509: certificate signed by unknown authority statusCode:0]
 Dropping document since it does not have all the required fields
Missing Fields: type
Required Fields: id, type


I am missing anything ? here

It looks like the document you are crawling does not have required fields i.e. type in your case. You can control field level settings under the Domain setting tab in the Admnistation.

Inside Attributes in the Domain Settings, you can control which fields are required in your content collection.
Inside the document extractor, since type(Content Type) is a required field by default, make sure you set
that field as below.
function extract(request, response) {
    $ = response.body;
    return [{
        'type': // logic to store the type field in the document,
    }];
}

Hope this helps!!!

I already have checked this and made the changes but still the same issue

@Manoj Are you setting the type field inside the document extractor..

No I am not setting the type field inside the document extractor

@Manoj ya that why you are getting this issue...I have updated the answer above to set type in document extractor. Let me know in case you have any queries.

you can find more details here on the document extractor..https://doc.sitecore.com/search/en/users/search-user-guide/create-a-javascript-document-extractor.html

Is there any way to make this required field as optional I tried to un check the required check box and publish it again , but I am unable to make it optional

@Manoj Both id and type are required by default..This is default schema structure...you can provide type as some random string inside document extractor to prevent this issue.since id is automatically generated therefore its not required to add it in the extractor..
